# One Form for entering/modifying information for multiple tables - WITHOUT SUBFORMS

Tags: ms-access

Long time reader on stackoverflow, first time writer.

I've been teaching myself MS Access365 for a few months now (with the help of hours and hours of Lynda.com classes). I have become quite proficient and so far have not encountered any problems that I couldn't fix without a little googling and cleverness. But now I've reached a point where I am stumped and I refuse to start all over and create a second form when I know: WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO MUST BE POSSIBLE WITH ONLY ONE FORM!

The idea is this:

The company has two primary sources of income.

1) Jobs worked by technicians on site.

2) Equipment rentals to other companies.

Hence I have two separate tables where I store details: "Jobs" & "Rentals"

I have another table where I store "Payments"! I have a form for entering new checks received by the company for jobs worked. It works beautifully right now for entering payments related to Jobs. Since the rentals feature of our company is new, I want to add the functionality to link a payment to ***EITHER Jobs or Rentals.***

So right now the form's overall record source is the "Payments" table and most of the boxes on the form are saving currency values or notes back to said "Payments" table. But at the very top of the form are a few boxes that help me change the status of the Job in "Jobs" table from within this Payment Entry form.

I'm accomplishing this like so:
The Payments table has a field for a JobCode that matches a JobCode in the "Jobs" table. I have a combo box set up for "JobCode" at the top of the form which populates with a query to show me unpaid jobs from the "Jobs" table. I can then select the Job the payment goes to and, get this, another combo box next to the first one auto populates to display the status of the job.

So when entering a payment for JobCode00034, I can see it was "PastDue", and now I can change it to "Partially Paid" since the check I am entering is only half of what is owed. So, even though the Payment Entry Form is mostly populated with information I am entering into the table "Payments", it does have a combo box where I ***change*** information stored in the "Jobs" table. I'm not entering any new data there, just altering existing data.

If you want to see what I'm talking about:

[JobCodeComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlnQC.png)

[JobStatusComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At1Yd.png)

This is all working fabulously!

Enter the new "Rentals" table.

I now want to use the same form to enter information for a check for a rental instead of a job. I set up two combo boxes under the first two that work the same way. All the properties are IDENTIAL but correspond to the new "Rental" tables and fields.

My RentalCode combo box has its record source in "Payments" but autopopulates with a query for unpaid RentalCodes in the "Rentals" table. Just like what I was doing with the JobCodes. Next to that box is a combo box that autopopulates once you select a RentalCode and shows you the status of that RentalCode in the "Rentals" table: ie, Paid, Pending, etc.

This is also working great on the form! I can enter all my info and select the rental and change the status.

Except after I enter all my check details *and try to exit the form*, Access prompts me with this error ***where it couldn't find a matching "JobCode" in the table "Jobs" and so it can't save my data***.

The errors (two in a row) read exactly as such:
"The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find a record in the table 'Jobs' with a key matching field(s) 'JobCode'."
"**You can't save this record at this time.** Microsoft Access may have encountered an error while trying to save a record. If you close this object now, the data changes you made will be lost. Do you want to close the database object anyway?"

I understand ***why*** Access can't find a matching JobCode. It's because I'm leaving that combo box blank since I'm not entering a payment relating to a job. How do I get around this and simply tell Access that it doesn't need to relate this payment to the "Jobs" table, because all the data I'm entering only pertains to "Payments" and "Rentals" ??

And a new bonus problem! Now that I've put these Rental combo boxes onto my form, it doesn't even function anymore for my Job Payment Entry. I get the same error codes if I leave the two Rental boxes empty and just try to submit a Job Payemt. Except of the course the error codes site the problem as "can't find a matching RentalCode"

TL;DR
Access won't let me submit a form because I am leaving some sections blank. ***I've already made sure those data sections are not "required" in the properties.*** How do I tell access to save the data I have entered and ignore all the other fields?

Thanks in advance for your help and ideas! :)

Comment: Have you established relationships in the Relationships Builder? Maybe remove them. Or maybe just don't enforce referential integrity.

Comment: I do have relationships established. I am concerned about turning off referential integrity, however, since that's going to open the floodgates for me to create new errors....

Comment: Understand but if you are going to do something out of the ordinary with your form design, it seems ignoring referential integrity is what you have to do to accomplish this. Other options may be UNBOUND form or if fields in both tables are same names, code can change form RecordSource and BOUND controls will still function. Or more code can even change the ControlSource of controls.

Comment: Okay, interesting. I didn't realize having fields with the same names in different tables could cause confusion for the RecordSource.

Comment: I did not say would cause confusion, although it can be a little if the tables are in the same query. Disregard my comments about the same field names, I was on wrong path there. If Payments has a field for JobCode AND a field for RentalCode AND referential integrity requires a value in both - well, just not going to work.